# Unresolved Symbols linking w/ Boost Serialization under Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ld

I'll start by stating I'm feeling like a moron tonight. I'm trying to minimally reproduce a work issue I have under RHEL5.6, gcc 4.1.2, boost 1.44.0, with Boost Serialization.

The environment I'm having *this* issue with is Ubuntu Server (with dev packages installed), gcc 4.7.2, and a build of boost 1.44.0 (against the system compiler, packages, etc).

My code compiles cleanly, but I'm getting a myriad of undefined symbols related to various `boost::archive` types.  Running strace on my make, I see it picking up the expected boost_serialization library:

```
668 43569 stat("/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib/libboost_serialization.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=700481, ...}) = 0
669 43569 open("/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib/libboost_serialization.so", O_RDONLY) = 8
```

My makefile is:

```
default: test-app
all: test-app

BOOST := /usr/local/boost/1.44.0

CPPFLAGS := -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Werror
INCDIRS := -isystem$(BOOST)/include
.LIBDIRS. := $(BOOST)/lib
.LIBS. :=boost_serialization
LIBS := $(foreach lib,$(.LIBS.),-l$(lib))
LIBDIRS := $(foreach dir,$(.LIBDIRS.),-L$(dir))
CPPFLAGS += $(INCDIRS)

base.o : base.cpp base.hpp
        g++ $(CPPFLAGS) --compile $< -o $@ -g

derived.o : derived.cpp base.hpp derived.hpp
        g++ $(CPPFLAGS) --compile $< -o $@ -g

main.o: main.cpp derived.hpp
        g++ $(CPPFLAGS) --compile $< -o $@ -g

test-app: main.o derived.o base.o
        g++ -o $@ $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS) $^

clean:
        rm -f *.o test
```

A (very) small sample of the linker errors I'm getting are like:

> base.o: In function `void
>   boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::save<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type
>   const&)':
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code,
>   char const*, char const*)'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()' base.o: In
>   function `void
>   boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::save<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type
>   const&)':
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code,
>   char const*, char const*)'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()' base.o: In
>   function `void
>   boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::ostream>::save<unsigned
>   int>(unsigned int const&)':
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code,
>   char const*, char const*)'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'
>   /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'

Likewise, if I do a symbol dump on the referenced .so's, I see the required symbols:

> objdump -t /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib/libboost_serialization.so |
>   c++filt | grep
>   "boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()"
>   000000000004e670 g     F .text  0000000000000065
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()
>   000000000004e6e0 g     F .text  0000000000000009              virtual
>   thunk to boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()
>   000000000004e6f0 g     F .text  0000000000000012
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()
>   000000000004ed60 g     F .text  000000000000005c
>   boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()
>   000000000004e710 g     F .text  0000000000000009              virtual
>   thunk to boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

I've been banging my head against the table for a while now...hoping someone can help. I don't think the specific source matters, but if requested, I can post it.

**Additional environmental details:**

> g++ --version g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 Copyright (C)
>   2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the
>   source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> ```
> ld --version
> GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22.90.20120924
> Copyright 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
> the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
> This program has absolutely no warranty.
> ```

Additionally, this is on a VM running under Hyper-V on Windows 8, although, I don't think that matters here.

**Complete link line:**
g++  -L/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib -lboost_serialization -o test-app main.o derived.o base.o

Comment: Just to isolate any issues that could be from the set of boost libraries from /usr/local, could you try to point your Makefile to pull the libraries and headers from the ones in /usr/lib and /usr/include instead and see if it compiles there successfully ?

Comment: Paste the actual link command `make` is running.

Comment: @n.m. done above. It's: g++  -L/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib -lboost_serialization -o test-app main.o derived.o base.o

Comment: @Tuxdude, initially I was building against the system boost (1.49.0), and I was receiving similar, if not identical, errors.

Comment: Try reordering your linker command arguments. Object files should go first and the libraries afterwards.

Comment: @n.m. I've tried the libs before & after the object files...same result. I know 'ld' is order dependent. Libs first is the first attempt I made.

Comment: I tried compiling a sample program using the boost serialization libraries on my system using a version of Makefile you provided and I did not have any issues. The file I tried is this one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp BTW the order of arguments to ld should not matter. Can you try compiling same example and see if you get any errors ?

Comment: Tuxdude, modifying my makefile and using the same above test app (copied from the source at libs/serialization/example.demo.cpp from my 1.44.0 source) - I get the same errors.

Comment: Check your lib with `nm -CD yourlib.so | grep yoursym`

Comment: I just want to say: I think this issue is an f'up on my end. I'm just not seeing it, and need help.  I'm not blaming boost, gcc/g++ or Ubuntu.

Comment: @NathanErnst - I tried the same demo.cpp with the exact Makefile which worked on openSUSE 12.2 on a Ubuntu 12.04 box and I get a similar set of undefined reference errors. :|

Comment: Also make sure your libraries and objects are the same architecture (i.e. all 32 or all 64 bits).

Comment: @n.m., all intermediate .o's are x86-64, as is libboost_serialization.so at /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib/libbost_serialization.so

Comment: So what did the `nm` check reveal?

Comment: Shows that the symbol exists:

nm /usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib/libboost_serialization.so | c++filt | grep "boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()"

000000000004e6f0 T boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

000000000004e670 T boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

000000000004ed60 T boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

000000000004e710 T virtual thunk to boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

000000000004e6e0 T virtual thunk to boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()

Comment: Also odd, I just tried the same code and makefile (with a few tweeks to paths) on a RHEL5.6 machine, and everything linked fine. So, maybe I am beginning to think there might be something wrong with my Ubuntu setup..

Comment: Are your boost libraries and headers coming from the same boost version?

Comment: Yeah. On a whim, tried against 1.53.0, same issue. I also tried adding all of the libs and object files into a linker group, no luck there, either.

Comment: If you cannot compile and link against distro-supplied boost as well, I suggest opening a bug in Ubuntu Launchpad.

Comment: It looks like something specific to Ubuntu, given I ran into the same error with Ubuntu 12.04 with the distro supplied libraries. Filing a bug in Launchpad sounds like the best idea for now.

Comment: And searching on google for **undefined reference to boost::archive::archive_exception** yields quite a lot of results on people having trouble linking against the boost serialization library but not one solid solution on how they got it fixed other than trying a different build. I'm not pointing fingers but it just looks to me that it has got something to do with the way the boost libraries are built. In addition I would try posting the question in the boost forum or mailing list if they have one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same problem, putting -lboost_serialization at the end like

> g++ -L/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib -o test-app main.o derived.o base.o -lboost_serialization

should solve it

Comment: I'll give this a shot later, once I'm home.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had tried using `-Wl,--start-group $(LIBS) $^ -Wl,--end-group`, and my understanding ordering shouldn't matter inside of a group. When I did `-Wl,--start-group $^ $(LIBS) -Wl,--end-group`, the link worked. Weird. Not sure why order should matter within a group.

Answer (score -1):

the binary object .o is not linked with libs.
first verify that in **/usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib** there are file's lib 
boost_serialization.
and next, that lib is registered:
    sudo ldconfig -v | grep boost_serialization

if not, create file **boost1.44.0.conf** in **/etc/ld.so.conf.d** with user root. With this ligne
    usr/local/boost/1.44.0/lib

then start this command
    sudo ldconfig -v | grep boost_serialization

Comment: This is wrong. Please don't do that. You are not supposed to go root and modify system-wide configs each time you want to link with a non-system library.

Comment: You need not touch ld.so.conf as long as you pass the correct search paths for linker using the -L option.